# Fazer busca em arquivo texto e comparar com outros

Tags: c#

Tenho duas listas de string. Recebido e Fixo. Bem, gostaria com apenas uma expressão lambda, percorrer a lista `Recebido` dentro da lista `Fixo` e caso não exista nenhum arquivo dentro de `Fixo`, eu guardo a esses arquivos que não existem em `Fixo` para depois deletá-los de dentro da lista Recebidos.

Exemplificando, tenho os seguintes arquivos a ser comparados:

```
odo_prs003a.asp
odo_gen0067b.asp
gen0001.js
estilo.css
```

E tenho essa lista fixa:

```
odo_prs003a.asp
cmc002a.asp
cmc0067d.asp
odo_gen0067b.asp
gen0001.js
ass0000.asp
calendar-br.js
css002c.css
```

Veja que na lista Fixa eu não tenho estilo.css, então esse arquivo é um potencial candidato a ser deletado.

Como eu faço isso usando lambda?

Comparo e não existindo na lista Fixa, eu guardo num array ou lista e depois eu deleto.

Fiz isso e agora preciso aplicar o lambda:

```
private bool ComparaArquivo(string recebido, string fixo)
        {
            List<string> _recebido = new List<string>();
            List<string> _fixo = new List<string>();

            try
            {
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Tente melhorar e simplificar a pergunta, está muito confuso. Tente criar [um exemplo mímino](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Comparar por nome não te ajudaria?

Comment: Creio que por Lâmbda seria a melhor forma, no momento. Fiz umas pesquisas e todos me disseram que o que eu quero dessa forma não dá, aí perguntei se por lambda eu teria uma performance melhor e todos me disseram que sim. Acho ser esse o caminho, mas manterei o post aberto para ver se algum ninja aparece aqui.

Comment: Fiz outra edição para melhorar o post. Espero que tenha melhorado.

Answer (score 2):

você pode até fazer com LINQ, seja usando `Query Syntax` ou `Method Syntax` (que você chamou de lambda), por uma questão de legibilidade, prefiro `Query Syntax`.

```
var lista = new List<string> {
    "odo_prs003a.asp",
    "odo_gen0067b.asp",
    "gen0001.js",
    "estilo.css"
};

var lfixa = new List<string> {
    "odo_prs003a.asp",
    "cmc002a.asp",
    "cmc0067d.asp",
    "odo_gen0067b.asp",
    "gen0001.js",
    "ass0000.asp",
    "calendar-br.js",
    "css002c.css",
};

var delQuery = 
    from item in lista
    join fixo in lfixa on item equals fixo into ljoin
    from test in ljoin.DefaultIfEmpty()
    where test == null
    select item;

var delMethod = lista
    .GroupJoin(lfixa, item => item, fixo => fixo, (item, fixo) => new { item, fixo })
    .SelectMany(list => list.fixo.DefaultIfEmpty(), (list, fixo) => new { list.item, fixo })
    .Where(list => list.fixo == null)
    .Select(list => list.item);

var delClasico = new List<string>();        
foreach (var item in lista)
{
    if (!lfixa.Contains(item))
    {
        delClasico.Add(item);
    }           
}

foreach (var item in delQuery)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

foreach (var item in delMethod)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}

foreach (var item in delClasico)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

No exemplo acima, realizo a busca utilizando a `Query Syntax` (armazeno o retorno em `delQuery`), `Method Syntax` (armazeno o retorno em `delMethod`) e usando um laço convencional (armazeno o retorno em `delClasico`).

Note que `Method Syntax` adiciona uma complexidade desnecesaria, `Query Syntax` tem exatamente o mesmo custo, porém o faz de uma forma mais elegante.

Poré, não vejo vantagem em utilizar `Linq` no lugar de um bom e velho laço for, seja por desempenho, legibilidade, ou qual quer outra razão oculta.

Como vejo que está tentando comparar duas estruturas de arquivos, vou te passar uma implementação... Ela recebe dois caminhos, então compara todos os arquivos com o mesmo nome... identificando todos os arquivos que pretecem apenas a uma estrutura de arquivos, e os arquivos que pertecem as duas estruturas, porém não são identicos:

```
public class Arquivo
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string NomeCompleto { get { return this.Path + this.Nome; } }
    public byte[] Hash { get; set; }
}
```

.

```
static void CompararPastas(string origemPath, string destinoPath)
{
    var arquivosOrigem = new List<Arquivo>();
    var arquivosDestino = new List<Arquivo>();

    var pastaOrigem = new DirectoryInfo(origemPath);
    var pastaDestino = new DirectoryInfo(destinoPath);

    LerPasta(pastaOrigem, origemPath, ref arquivosOrigem);
    LerPasta(pastaDestino, destinoPath, ref arquivosDestino);

    var somenteOrigem =
        from arquivoOrigem in arquivosOrigem
        join arquivoDestino in arquivosDestino on arquivoOrigem.NomeCompleto equals arquivoDestino.NomeCompleto into notInDestino
        from arquivoDestino in notInDestino.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where arquivoDestino == null
        select arquivoOrigem;

    foreach (var arquivo in somenteOrigem)
    {
        //arquivo não presente no destino, você pode copiar o mesmo para a origem.
    }

    var somenteDestino =
        from arquivoDestino in arquivosDestino
        join arquivoOrigem in arquivosOrigem on arquivoDestino.NomeCompleto equals arquivoOrigem.NomeCompleto into notInOrigem
        from arquivoOrigem in notInOrigem.DefaultIfEmpty()
        where arquivoOrigem == null
        select arquivoDestino;

    foreach (var arquivo in somenteDestino)
    {
        //arquivo não presente na origem, você pode apagar o mesmo para o destino.
    }

    var modificados =
        from arquivoOrigem in arquivosOrigem
        join arquivoDestino in arquivosDestino on arquivoOrigem.NomeCompleto equals arquivoDestino.NomeCompleto
        where arquivoOrigem.Hash != arquivoDestino.Hash
        select arquivoOrigem;

    foreach (var arquivo in modificados)
    {
        //arquivo na origem é diferente do arquivo no destino, você pode substituir o arquivo da origem pelo destino;
    }
}

static void LerPasta(DirectoryInfo pasta, string basePath, ref List<Arquivo> arquivos)
{
    foreach (var subPasta in pasta.GetDirectories())
    {
        LerPasta(subPasta, basePath, ref arquivos);
    }

    foreach (var arquivo in pasta.GetFiles())
    {
        LerArquivo(arquivo, basePath, ref arquivos);
    }
}

static void LerArquivo(FileInfo arquivo, string basePath, ref List<Arquivo> arquivos)
{
    var file = new Arquivo();
    file.Path = arquivo.DirectoryName.Replace(basePath, string.Empty);
    file.Nome = arquivo.Name;
    using (var lobjLeitura = arquivo.OpenRead())
    {
        using (var lobjSha512 = new SHA256Managed())
        {
            file.Hash = lobjSha512.ComputeHash(lobjLeitura);
        }
    }
    arquivos.Add(file);
}
```

Comment: Olá Toby, não posso fazer dessa forma. Eu apenas fiz um exemplo, mas são mais de 3.500 arquivos e diariamente e às vezes mais de uma vez por dia, logo não posso carregar manualmente assim. Veja a minha edição. Não tem como carregar arquivo a arquivo.

Comment: @pnet, a lista fixa serve apenas para exemplificar, você pode fazer as consultas usando listas bem maiores..

Comment: @pnet, vou adicionei um script para comparar arquivos e a estrutura dos arquivos, pode lhe se util.

Comment: Toby, seu exemplo parece bom, mas não consegui fazer rodar, porque? Bem, em uma lista tenho nomes de arquivos que estão em uma pasta. Na outra a ser comparada, eu tenho um txt com vários nomes de arquivos dentro. Logo eu tenho a primeira lista com, 10, 12 ou n nomes de arquivos, mas na outra terei sempre um(com vários nomes), que representa o arquivo txt que é um apenas. Isso tá me dando alguma dificuldade.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o metodo **Except**. No código a seguir, a variável `resultado` armazenará os registros que não estão presentes na lista `_fixo`. Caso queira que o resultado seja os registros que existem em comum nas duas listas, você pode utilizar o metodo **Intersect**.

```
var resultado = _recebido.Except(_fixo);
```

Veja funcionando no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/OYtClJ)